# Issue with jQuery and Telerik?

Tags: jquery, telerik

I have the following jQuery which renders 5 stars and may or may not have some lit up golden. It is housed in a RadPopupWindow (Telerik). From one page you can click and receive this popup and code and everything works as expected. From another page, it renders the user's votes and the link 'Remove my vote' for a split second, then it goes away. So it half works, and half doesn't.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //if they've already voted, show the stars
        var nbrStarsVoted = $('#<%= hdfStarRating.ClientID %>').val();
        if (nbrStarsVoted > 0) {
            $('#removeVote').text('Remove my vote');
            //show stars, then addClass jQuery-ratings-full to light up the right amount of stars
            $('#starRating div:lt(' + nbrStarsVoted + ')').addClass('jquery-ratings-full');

        }

        //add correct class to star they've clicked on, and the ones before it
        $('.jquery-ratings-star').click(function () {
            $(this)
                .prevAll().addBack().addClass('jquery-ratings-full').end().end()
                .nextAll().removeClass('jquery-ratings-full');
            //make (this) be what's stored in the hiddenfield for postback (casting the vote)
            $('#<%= hdfStarRating.ClientID %>').val(this.id);
         });


        //remove their vote
        $('#removeVote').click(function () {
            $('#starRating div:lt(' + nbrStarsVoted + ')').removeClass('jquery-ratings-full');
            $('#removeVote').hide();
            $('#<%= hdfStarRating.ClientID %>').val(0);
        });


    });
</script>
```

And here is the HTML and CSS. I've tested it out in jsFiddle, Codepen, it all works great. Just from one page to the next it does not. Any ideas?

```
<div style="float: left" id="starRating">
   <div class="jquery-ratings-star" id="1"></div>
   <div class="jquery-ratings-star" id="3"></div>
   <div class="jquery-ratings-star" id="4"></div>
   <div class="jquery-ratings-star" id="5"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .jquery-ratings-star {
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        background-image: url('/../ESDNET/Images/Icons/star_disabled.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 2px;
    }

    .jquery-ratings-full {
        background-image: url('/../ESDNET/Images/Icons/star.png');
    }
</style>
```

I should point out that there is a RadScriptManager on the popup page and there is Telerik all over the site. Apparently I'm the first to come along and try to throw jQuery into the mix and it is not jiving well at all.

Comment: There's nothing clearly wrong with the code above. After the javascript has run, something must happen to the page, probably another piece of javascript that negates the golden stars. This could be a `....removeClass('jquery-ratings-full')` expression or something that replaces the stars with new ones. Less likely is that a CSS style sheet is lazy-loaded with a directive that redefines `.jquery-ratings-full`. Inspect the would-be golden stars with Firebug or similar to see which classes are applied. That will give you a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to determine that this was not an issue with the code but something else entirely. I am leaving the question here in the hopes that it help someone else down the line.